# How can I implement a Typeclass for a generic type?

Tags: haskell

I am trying to implement a Typeclass called `Eval` that evaluates the type `Expression` that I defined previously. Here is my declaration of the typeclass

```hs
class Eval a where
  eval :: Expression -> a
```

Now, I want `eval` to return different types depending on the expression. For instance, `1 + 1` should be evaluated to type `Int` whereas `1.5 + 1` should be evaluated to type float.

In order to not repeat myself I wanted to implement the operators '+', '-', and '*' for all `Num` types so I wrote

```hs
instance (Num a) => Eval a where
  eval (Number n) = (read n :: a)
  ...
```

this gives me the Error

```
     Illegal instance declaration for ‘Eval a’
        (All instance types must be of the form (T a1 ... an)
         where a1 ... an are *distinct type variables*,
         and each type variable appears at most once in the instance head.
         Use FlexibleInstances if you want to disable this.)
    • In the instance declaration for ‘Eval a’
   |
15 | instance Eval a where
   |     
     ^^^^^^
```

Is there any way I can achieve my goal? If so how do I do it?

Comment: How do you intend to use `eval` from the rest of your (typed) program?  Sketch that code, it will elucidate this question.

Comment: Also, this is a good question. There are many similar problems and the title is informative. Just because there isn't a good "direct" answer doesn't mean it's not a good question.  What's with the down votes?

Comment: For a given expression, I would do some kind of typechecking to determine what the type of the expression is and then call eval on the expression. So if I determine that the expression evaluates to int I would call `eval expr :: Int` where `expr` is my expression.

Let me know if I should be more specific.

Edit: If it helps, I am implementing a complier and the Expression type is an Abstract Syntax Tree of parsed code.

Comment: ah, if you intend to type switch on the result, rather than dispatching based on context, a typeclass is the wrong tool. You want to use an algebraic data type and list the possible types. `data Value = VInt Int | VFloat Float | ...` and then `eval` is just a regular function returning `Value`

Comment: Could you elaborate on how I should be using an algebraic data type and list the possible types? Do you mean I should create a type like 
```haskell
data PossibleTypes = Int Int | Float Float | ...
```
and have haskell return that?

Comment: Gotcha. Wouldn't it be possible to have `eval` be a function like `read` that takes the same input but the return type depends on what's needed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211736/discussion-between-tippfehler-and-luqui).